# Passing a string from IBAction to a separate View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to pass a String from an IBAction in my DetailsViewController to the viewDidLoad in my WebViewController to call up a URL in the WebView.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

My Code:

```
// DetailsViewController.m

- (IBAction)edu1Link:(id)sender {

    NSString *webURL = [[NSString webURL] initWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];


    _webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];

    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];            
}


// WebViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webURL]]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a property in your `WebViewController` and set that property in the action before presenting the view controller.

Comment: Yes, just like this: `_webViewController.myURLProperty = webURL;`.

Comment: what goes in place of myURLProperty?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way would be to use a delegate methode
here is a [tutorial](http://timneill.net/2010/11/modal-view-controller-example-part-2/) how you would do that

Answer (score 0):

What albertamg is referring to is Objective-C properties. They are very powerful. Take a peak here: http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Properties are like instance fields in Java. They're helpful in side-stepping zero-parameter-methods.